# Kendo Ui Grid - dataItem.set() method not working properly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid with 4 columns name, age, collection, profit. But when I try to set a number column it's not reflecting on grid.

```
schema:
{
    model:{
        fields:{
            name:{type:"string"},
            age:{type:"number"},
            collection: { type:"number", defaultValue:0.00},
            profit: { type:"number", defaultValue:0.00}
        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.at(0);
data.set("name", "John Doe");
```

But I want to update numeric column:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.at(0);
var collectionVal = 50000;
data.set("collection", collectionVal);
```

And it's not updating because the column is of type "number".

**UPDATE:**

```
pageable: 
{
    refresh  : true,
    pageSizes: true
},
edit: function(e) 
{
    $('input[name="age"]').blur(function()
    {
        mygrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        selectedRow = mygrid.select();
        dataItem = mygrid.dataItem(selectedRow);

        dataItem.collection = dataItem.age * dataItem.profit;
        dataItem.set("collection", dataItem.collection);
    });
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly well, check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MWvKc/

Comment: @OnaBai thanks, it works perfectly.. one more thing, I don't want the buttons to set value, so can you help me to set collection = (age * profit) when user changes the age. See updated code above :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of updating `collection` in a `blur` handler defined in the `edit`, define a `save` event handler in your grid as follow:

```
pageable  : {
    refresh  : true,
    pageSizes: true
},
save      : function (e) {
    var profit = e.values.profit || e.model.profit;
    var age = e.values.age || e.model.age;
    this.dataSource.getByUid(e.model.uid).set("collection", age * profit);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, seems like I don't have the basics.. it worked :) and even I'm working on dynamic fields for the grid, "fetching rows from database and using them as columns"

Comment: need solution once again, this code is not updating multiple columns.. what changes are needed if I want to update 3 rows at a time?

Comment: can you suggest me the solution for multiple field changes.. I'm still stacked at same issue, thanks

Comment: What is the problem with multiple fields? Did you submit a new question with the details? Can you send me the link and I'll take a look?

Comment: nope I did not submitted new question. Problem: I have 5 fields, when I update profit field it will update all the other 5 fields. (field 1- 10%, field 2-20%, field 3-30% and so) according to new profit value.. the issue with your given solution is, it goes multiple time inside the save() and it changes my whole calculation. right now I have solved it with flag condition, but it's not the correct way.